# Wait for it to resolve promise and then insert MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, wordpress

I have code in Nodejs, which will insert a post first, and then a meta post (other table).

I want the post to be inserted first, and then do a search for the last ID and insert the meta post (other table).

But it is not working, it seems that it does not wait for that the first function to insert the post.

Here is my code:

```
function insertarpost() { 
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
        var sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_posts` ( `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`,`post_excerpt`, `post_status`,`comment_status`, `ping_status`,`post_password`, `post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_parent`, `guid`,`menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`,`comment_count`) VALUES (1, '"+fhoy+"', '"+fhoy+"', ' ', '"+title+"','', 'publish', 'open', 'closed','','"+slug+"','','', '"+fhoy+"', '"+fhoy+"','', '0','','0', 'movies','' ,0);"; 
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) { 
            if (err) throw err; 
            resolve(result); 
            console.log("1 registro insertado"); 
        }); 
    }); 
}

insertarpost().then(obtenerultimopostid())

function obtenerultimopostid() {
    con.query("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;", function (err, result, fields) {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ("+result[0].ID+",'runtime', '"+runtime+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'original_title','"+titleoriginal+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'Rated','"+cpgrated+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'Country', '"+country+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'date', '"+datemovie+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'imdbRating', '"+repimdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'vote_average', '"+reptmdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'imdbVotes', '"+quantimdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'vote_count', '"+quanttmdb+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'tagline', '"+tagline+"'),("+result[0].ID+",'dt_poster', '"+poster+"');"; 
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) { 
            if (err) throw err; 
            console.log("1 registro wpmeta insertado");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are *executing* the second function immediately, instead of *passing* the function to the `then` method:

Change:

```
insertarpost().then(obtenerultimopostid())
```

to:

```
insertarpost().then(obtenerultimopostid)
```

Not your question, but your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is real nice of you.